# Redirection loop on product page magento 1.9

Tags: product, page, app

I'm experiencing a strange issue on products page...

www.domain.com/product.html?a1=v1&a2=v2

is taking me to

www.domain.com/product.html?a1=v1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;a2=v2

Any ideas will be helpfull.

Have tried this:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]

But this is only redirecting to 
www.domain.com/index.php?a1=v1&a2=v2

And I ofcouse need to stay on the product page.

Comment: share full rewrite condition.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]

Thanks for answering

Comment: @kunj
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]

Comment: The problem in my case is produced by creareSeo extension. You have to disable Canonical Product Redirecting